# Laravel 5 Class not found error in middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

[image]I have created a middleware in laravel 5 called IpHitsCounter which uses a model called DeviceInfo which is inside App\Models\FrontEnd

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware\FrontEnd;

    use Closure;
    use Request;
    use BrowserDetect;
    use App\Models\FrontEnd\DeviceInfo;
    use DB;

    class IpHitsCounter {

        /**
         * Handle an incoming request.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Closure  $next
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
         DeviceInfo::create(['devices'=>$agentDevice,'deviceFamily'=>$deviceFamily]);
        }
```

My Code for Model is:

```
<?php namespace App\Models\FrontEnd;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DeviceInfo extends Model {

   /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'client_device_infos';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['devices', 'deviceFamily'];



}
```

When doing so I am getting the following error: `Class 'App\Models\FrontEnd\DeviceInfo' not found`

although the class exists still I am getting the error.

Comment: try composer dump-autoload

Comment: tried already doesnot work @GauravDave

Comment: Is your model in the right directory? Should be `app/Models/FrontEnd/DeviceInfo.php`

Comment: yes i have checked  it is there @lukasgeiter

Comment: what is there in `line 31` of the `IpHitsCounter` file ?

Comment: DeviceInfo::create(['devices'=>$agentDevice,'deviceFamily'=>$deviceFamily]); this code for ease I only showed this code in my question as error was occuring due to it

Comment: But, if I count the lines you provided for middleware, there are only 21 lines. And on line 20, you have that `DeviceInfo::create()` method. I cannot see more lines. So would you mind showing the full source code of the middleware ?

Comment: i had made my model without using the artisan command and I made my model again using the artisan command and everything worked fine thanks for looking into my problem though @user3514160

Comment: Glad that you resolved the query on your own.. :)

Answer (score 17):

I guess you forgot to register the `middleware`.

Open the file `app/Http/Kernel.php`

Look for the `$routeMiddleware` property.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
    'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
    'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
    'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
    'App\Http\Middleware\FrontEnd\IpHitsCounter' // your middleware
];
```

**UPDATE 1: 28th August, 2016**

Since Laravel 5.3.* is released, there are some configurations in the routes file. Before 5.3, there was only 1 file called `routes.php`, but now, there are 2 files, `web.php` and `api.php` and both of these files are listed at the root directory of projects inside `routes` folder. Feel free to check it out.

Coming to the solution, you need to open `app/Http/Kernel.php` and edit the `$middlewareGroups` having the key of `web`. So, it should look somewhat like this:

```
'web' => [
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,

    \App\Http\Middleware\FrontEnd\IpHitsCounter::class // your middleware
],
```

Comment: i have done that added as a `protected $routeMiddleware` dont think it would have run without doing so everything is fine with the middleware its working but my only problem is the use of model I have created

Comment: as the comment by @lukasgeiter, is the name of the file correct and at the right place ? Cross check it to confirm.

Comment: Can you please provide the `stacktrace` ?

Comment: That's the array of global middlewares. If you put your middleware there then it will be executed with every HTTP request. Check here http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#registering-middleware. This answer is absolutely wrong.